# How can I list all answers from answer model to my question model in Django ? Relation many to one?

Tags: python, django, for-loop, django-models

I would like to ask you for your help.

I have two models. Question and Answer. One question can have many answers. My models looks like this:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    answered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    votesscore = models.IntegerField(default='0')
    amountofvotes = models.IntegerField(default='0')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question


class Answer(models.Model):
    question_id = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, null=True)
    answer = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    votesscore = models.IntegerField(default='0')
    amountofvotes = models.IntegerField(default='0')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.answer
```

Here is my views.py:

```
def home(request):
    allquestionswithanswers = Answer.objects.prefetch_related('question_id')
    allquestionswithoutanswers = Question.objects.filter(answered = False)
    return render(request, 'main/home.html', {'allquestionswithanswers': allquestionswithanswers, 'allquestionswithoutanswers': allquestionswithoutanswers})
```

And here is my home.html:

```
<h1>Questions with answers:</h1>
<ul>
    {% for allquestionwithanswer in allquestionswithanswers %}
    <li>
        {{ allquestionwithanswer.question_id }} {{ allquestionwithanswer.user }}<br><br>
        <br><br>
        {{ allquestionwithanswer.answer }}
    </li>
    {% endfor %}

</ul>

<h1>Questions without answers:</h1>
<ul>
    {% for allquestionwithoutanswer in allquestionswithoutanswers %}
    <li>
        {{ allquestionwithoutanswer.question }} {{ allquestionwithoutanswer.user }}
        <br><br>
        {{ allquestionwithoutanswer.answer }}
    </li>
    {% endfor %}

</ul>
```

And some things are working and some not and I don't get how can I fix them :(

I have working "Questions with answers:". It is listing my question, and corresponding answer, but if question has multiple answers, it is printing question many times, each time with next answer. I would like to look it like this:
-Question 1
    -Answer 1
    -Answer 2
-Question 1
    -Answer1

I know that I should go with nested loops but I experimented with it and I cannot get it to work.

And my second problem is. In "Questions without answers:" I want to list all question where boolean "answered" = False. But it is possible to have it set to false but have some answers and if it occurs, I would like to list those answers too. But here I have problem with models, since Question model don't have information about answer. It works only in other way.

I would be really grateful for any help and directions.

Thanks and Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the problem where it is printing the question multiple times, you have to look at what your loop is actually doing:

```
{% for allquestionwithanswer in allquestionswithanswers %}
    <li>
        {{ allquestionwithanswer.question_id }} {{ allquestionwithanswer.user }}
        <br><br><br><br>
        {{ allquestionwithanswer.answer }}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Here, you are looping through the collection of `allquestionswithanswers` - but, this is not a collection of questions, it is a collection of answers! So you are executing the loop for every answer in the collection and you are printing out the question and answer each time the loop runs (one per answer in the collection).

You need to work from a collection of `questions` - and you are incorrect that the relationship only works one way. Your questions are aware of the answers associated with them. In fact, there is a Django convention to retrieve the answer set for a particular question. You append `_set` to the name of the model, in this case it would be `answer_set`. For your models, you would use a queryset of `question.answer_set.all` to get all of the answers for a particular question.

So try this:

In your view:

```
def home(request):
    allquestionswithanswers = Question.objects.filter(answered = True)
    allquestionswithoutanswers = Question.objects.filter(answered = False)

    return render(request, 'main/home.html', {'allquestionswithanswers': allquestionswithanswers, 'allquestionswithoutanswers': allquestionswithoutanswers})
```

and in the view template:

```
<h1>Questions with answers:</h1>
<ul>
    {% for question in allquestionswithanswers %}
        <li>
            {{ question.id }} {{ question.user }}
            <br><br><br><br>
            {% for answer in question.answer_set.all %}
                {{ answer }}
            {% endfor %}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

<h1>Questions without answers:</h1>
<ul>
    {% for question in allquestionswithoutanswers %}
        <li>
            {{ question }} {{ question.user }}
            <br><br>
            {% for answer in question.answer_set.all %}
                {{ answer }}
            {% endfor %}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Let me know how that works. Also, if you haven't already, work through the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/) from start to finish. It walks you through creating a poll application, which is almost the exact same model structure as your app (questions/answers).

Comment: Thank you very much! It is working. I don't know why I was stuck on this answer and question_id. It was stupid from the beginning.

I will go through this tutorial that you have linked. And I will also read about this "_set.all" thing. Thanks! :)

Comment: Glad I could help!